# Retrieve previously blocked data after login in firebase

Tags: firebase, firebase-security, firebase-authentication

The question itself is simple: For a Firebase app, How do you get data that was previously blocked after you login and it is no longer blocked?

As for the details that lead me to ask this question:

In this particular app, I use a simple layout with 2 main sub trees of the root tree, Users and Data. The Data tree is completely readable, anyone can read it at any time. The Users tree is almost the opposite, with the only exception being if you are logged in, then you can read a specific sub tree that is yours only. This leads to the problem that when you go to the page, this data that may be very important to you is blocked until you log in, and there is no way to retrieve it directly. After you log in, however, you now have permission to get that information, but because it was previously blocked, There seems to be no way to extract it.

I have scoured the docs and found only one trigger that might be useful, onAuth(), but even though I can run stuff after login, I cant actually get any data. The best I have gotten so far was a Firebase Reference to the specific sub tree I need, but I cant find any way to actually use that reference to get the Snapshot because it is after the page load. It seems the only option I have is to refresh the page after login and check for login on page load, but that is an awful lot of overhead. Is there some other way to get the data in a tree that you previously did not have permission for after you log in and do have permission to read it? Might there be some reference in the docs I can't find or don't understand that allows me to demand a new snapshot of a fire base reference that is not through triggers that can only be defined on pageload?

Comment: If your page wants to load data that needs authentication, you should attach your listeners after authentication occurred (i.e. in `onAuth()`). If you're having trouble making that work, it's going to be a lot easier to help if you share a [snippet of code that shows the problem](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen Thanks to your recommendation, i finally got it working. I wrote up the code to work as you described, and then continued debugging it until i found the main issue. So the acceptable answer is simply your first sentence. Make it an answer and i will accept it. Feel free to include the idea that if it is not working, its probably a specific logic or syntax error, or perhaps even a very short rudimentary  chunk of code that would do it. Otherwise i will at some later time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Frank van puffelen is right.

It is as simple as:

```
// setup and other code
ref = new Firebase(URL);                       //The firebase reference
myuserid = null;                               //Storage variable
myname = null;                                 //Storage variable

//Other code

//Start of answer code

ref.onAuth(function(authData) {                //ON login status change

    if (ref.getAuth()) {                       //Are they logged in
        myuserid = authData.uid;               //Stores their UID for use
        userbase = 'Users/' + authData.uid;    //Get path to user info
        ref.child(userbase).on("value", function(snapshot, prevChildKey) {
            var newData = snapshot.val();      //get data
            console.log(newData);              //View data, confirmed it was what I wanted
            myname = newData.name;             //The important data I needed
        })
    }
})
```

It seems that so long as this listener is by the other listeners, it works. It runs every time the Authentication is changed, and if they are logged in, attaching a listener to the path with the information and getting it. I am sure there are better ways and probably some problems with this code, but it works for me.